# find all entities by nested list that don't have some value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have tables NighClub, Visitor and Visitors_NighClub (many to many). **I need to get all night clubs which DONT HAVE certain Visitor.**

To get NightClubs which HAVE certain Visitor I do like this:

```
SELECT nc.id, nc.name
  FROM night_club as nc
    INNER JOIN visitor_night_clubs as vnc ON nc.id = vnc.night_clubs_id 
    WHERE vnc.visitors_id = 3;
```

But how to get all nightClubs that DONT HAVE some certain Visitor. I cant do like:

```
WHERE vnc.visitors_id != 3;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure this out

```
SELECT *
    FROM night_club 
    WHERE night_club.id NOT IN 
(SELECT nc.id
  FROM night_club as nc
    INNER JOIN visitor_night_clubs as vnc ON nc.id = vnc.night_clubs_id 
    WHERE vnc.visitors_id = 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a correlated subquery

```
SELECT nc.id, nc.name
  FROM night_club as nc
    INNER JOIN visitor_night_clubs as vnc ON nc.id = vnc.night_clubs_id 
    WHERE not exists 
         (select 1 from visitor_night_clubs as vnc1 where vnc.night_clubs_id=vnc1.night_clubs_id and vnc1.visitors_id=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

use not in

```
SELECT nc.id, nc.name
  FROM night_club as nc
    INNER JOIN visitor_night_clubs as vnc ON nc.id = vnc.night_clubs_id 
    WHERE vnc.visitors_id not in( 3,....)
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend `not exists` for this purpose:

```
select nc.*
from night_club nc
where not exists (select 1
                  from visitor_night_clubs vnc
                  where vnc.night_clubs_id = nc.id and
                        vnc.visitors_id = 4
                 );
```

Why is `NOT EXISTS` better than `NOT IN`?  Simple reason:  `NOT IN` does not do what you expect when *any* value returned by the subquery is `NULL`.  That just makes it dangerous to use.  Although you can filter out `NULL` values, always using `NOT EXISTS` means that this is never an issue.

Also note the use of table aliases and that no `JOIN` is needed in the subquery.

Comment: @AntonKolosok . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?